# how to keep column's names after one hot encoding sklearn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science, one-hot-encoding

I am working on the titanic kaggle competition, to deal with categorical data I’ve splited the data into 2 sets: one for numerical variables and the other for categorical variables.
After working with sklearn one hot encoding on the set with categorical variables I tried the regroup the two datasets but since the categorical set is an ndarray and the other one is a dataframe I used:

```
np.hstack((X_train_num, X_train_cat))
```

which works perfectly but I no longer have the names of my variables.

Is there another way to do this while maintaining the names of the variables without using pd.get_dummies()?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
X_train = X_train_num.join(
   pd.DataFrame(X_train_cat, X_train_num.index).add_prefix('cat_')
)
```

Comment: I think this is the better answer. (Well, I think you should use `pd.get_dummies`, but asides from that, this is the better answer.)

Comment: Thanks @AmiTavory

Answer (score 3):

Well, as you stated in your question, there's `pd.get_dummies`, which I think is the best choice here. Having said that, you could use

```
pd.concat([X_train_num, pd.DataFrame(X_train_cat, index=X_train_num.index)], axis=1)
```

If you like, you could give also useful column names with

```
pd.concat([X_train_num, pd.DataFrame(X_train_cat, index=X_train_num.index, columns=cols)], axis=1)
```

and `cols` can be whatever list of strings you want (of the appropriate length).

Answer (score 1):

Adding columns in sklearn onehot encoder

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
OH_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
OH_cols_train = pd.DataFrame(OH_encoder.fit_transform(dev_data[object_cols]))
OH_cols_valid = pd.DataFrame(OH_encoder.transform(test_data[object_cols]))

# Adding column names to the encoded data set.
OH_cols_train.columns = OH_encoder.get_feature_names(object_cols)
OH_cols_valid.columns = OH_encoder.get_feature_names(object_cols)

# One-hot encoding removed index; put it back
OH_cols_train.index = dev_data.index
OH_cols_valid.index = test_data.index

# Remove categorical columns (will replace with one-hot encoding)
num_X_train = dev_data.drop(object_cols, axis=1)
num_X_valid = test_data.drop(object_cols, axis=1)

# Add one-hot encoded columns to numerical features
dev_data = pd.concat([num_X_train, OH_cols_train], axis=1)
test_data = pd.concat([num_X_valid, OH_cols_valid], axis=1)
```